# Nhibernate 3.3 Lazy loading one-to-one association

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I read on the NHibernate changelog of version 3.3 that you can now lazyload one-to-one associations, which was not possible before, I've tried setting up lazy on my association but it still gets eager-loader, how would the mapping be for lazy loaded one-to-one association? I'm using fluentNhibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since proxies can only be generated if it is guaranteed that there is a target available (since NHibernate can't replace the proxy with null when it's loaded), NHibernate needs to know that your one-to-one association is constrained in the database. This is done with the `constrained` attribute on the `<one-to-one>` tag.